# JPA Many to Many cascade not working

Tags: java, jpa

I have 2 entities `User` and `Product`, and also I have `Star` relation. User can mark many products with star, and product can be marked by many users.

I have the entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
@XmlRootElement
public class User implements Serializable {

    @JoinTable(name = "STARED", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "BUYER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")})
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<Product> staredProductsCollection;

    // More fields........
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCTS")
@XmlRootElement
public class Product implements Serializable {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "staredProductsCollection")
    private Collection<User> staredUsersCollection;

    // More fields.......
}
```

So the user is the owner. But when I tries to update the star list:

```
User user = userFacade.find(1);
Product product = productFacade.find(1);
user.getStaredProductsCollection().add(product);
userFacade.edit(user);
productFacede.find(1).getStaredUsersCollection().size() // Stays 0.....
```

And the `edit` method is

```
public void edit(User user) {
    em.merge(user);
    em.flush();
}
```

Why the product's `staredUsersCollection` is not update even the user have `CascadeType.ALL` annotation? Now I have to restarts the server to see the changes. So how can I make it update?

---

**EDIT**
Thanks to ujulu, the fix to the insert is:

```
User user = userFacade.find(1);
Product product = productFacade.find(1);
user.getStaredProductsCollection().add(product);
product.getStaredUsersCollection().add(user);
userFacade.edit(user);
productFacede.find(1).getStaredUsersCollection().size() // Now it 1!!
```

But now the removing not working:

```
User user = userFacade.find(1);
Product product = productFacade.find(1);
user.getStaredProductsCollection().remove(product); // Returns true
product.getStaredUsersCollection().remove(user); // Returns true
userFacade.edit(user);
productFacede.find(1).getStaredUsersCollection().size() // Stay on 1.....
```

Comment: Try doing a em.flush() after the call to userFacade.edit(user) and see if that works.

Comment: @Sashi Adding `em.flush()` didn't worked... Stays the same

Comment: can you turn on 'show_sql' flag to verify the insert/update statements after em.flush()?

Comment: @Sashi I can see that it saved correctly in the `STARED` table. And how can I turn on the `show_sql` flag?

Comment: I don't see in your code above that you added the `user` to the `stareddUserCollection`? If you haven't done that somewhere else or you haven't added any data in the database manually the collection is empty.

Comment: @ujulu You are right, when I add `product.getStaredUsersCollection().add(user);` it works.. But removing with the same way not working. I will update the question

Comment: Try with `orphanRemoval=true` on both `@ManyToMany` annotations.

Comment: There is no `orphanRemoval` attribute in `@ManyToMany` annotation.

Comment: You are right. There is no this element for the annotation.

Comment: Is the size of `StaredProductsCollection` also 1 after removing?

Comment: No, it updates to 0 correctly. Only the  `StaredUsersCollection` is wrong (going up when adding, but no going down when deleting). If I do `productFacade.edit(product)`, it updates correctly. But it is weird, why I need to merges for that?

Answer (score 0):

EntityManager.find() retrieves the object from PersistenceContext if it has already been loaded. You are most likely doing a count on cached version of the object.

[EntityManager.find()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#find(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object))

Refresh the 'product' object from database.

```
em.refresh(product).getStaredUsersCollection().size()
```

Or clear cache -

```
em.clear()
productFacede.find(1).getStaredUsersCollection().size()
```

I think detaching the entity might work too -

```
em.detach(product)
productFacede.find(1).getStaredUsersCollection().size()
```

Comment: Didn't work... `refresh` throws exception `Cannot refresh unmanaged object`, `clear` and `detach` didn't works

Comment: Do you have a transaction manager? Where does you transaction begin and end?

Comment: No, I am doing only what I have wrote in the question... I am not handling the transactions